# Best control to load big bodies of text in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I have to load a big chunk of text from my database, are labels the way to go?
I am loading several strings of text from an object for a news site I'm pretending to do with asp.net and I was wondering if Label was the only option

Comment: A `Label` would wrap the text in some markup, I think a `<span>`.  A `Literal` won't.  You could even just emit the value directly to the page without a control.  There's little difference between any of the approaches.  Try one and see if there's an actual problem.

Comment: you mean a label inside a span?

Comment: A `Label` *creates* a `<span>`.  Putting one inside a `<span>` would create a nested `<span>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Label and Literal can be one of your options, but `<asp:Literal` is lightweight than Label, gets more lightweight if `<asp:literal enableviewstate='false'`

> A Literal control is much more light weight than a Label.. it's meant to write out text/html directly to the browser. A Label is little bulkier than a Literal, but has all benefits of a WebControl such as styling options etc.

Hope this helps!